# prompt-toolkit terminate program when idle

Tags: python, prompt-toolkit

I am trying to write a simple command line application with `prompt-toolkit`. It works quite well, however I want to quit the program if there was no input for a long time. This turned out to be very challenging for me.

Here is some pseudo code for what the cli app should kind of work like:

```
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
import time

def execute(cmd):
    # do long task
    time.sleep(120)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = PromptSession()

    while True:
        start_time = time.time()
        cmd = s.prompt('>')
        execute(cmd)

        if time.time() - start_time > 60:
            break
```

So the program should terminate if the user didn't issue a command in the last 60 seconds. But if a command is executed which takes longer than 60 seconds, it should only be terminated 60 seconds after the command finished (and no new command was issued).

I already stumble over the first bit. Do I need parallel processing to check the time while `s.prompt` is running? There is also a `prompt_async` version of the command. I played around with it, but didn't have any success...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found a very simple answer for my question in the asyncio documentation, which does exactly what I searched for: `asyncio.wait_for`.
The solution is here, just for the record:

```
from prompt_toolkit import PromptSession
import asyncio

def execute(cmd):
    # do long task
    time.sleep(120)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = PromptSession()

    while True:
        try:
            cmd = await asyncio.wait_for(s.prompt_async('>'), timeout=60)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            break
        execute(cmd)
```